# javascript regex examples - extract until character appears?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text like this.

```
Mr John Smith , Mr James Smith                  +(21)-(21)-12345678, 12345678, 12345678                     +(21)-12345678, 12345678, 12345678        SomeTextHereAlso        +(21)-(22)-12345678                       www.somewebaddress.co.uk                            Some Title, Some Place , Some Town,Some Suburb,  City - 100000
```

I want to extract each of these strings using regex in javascript. I found some examples and this morning they worked. Now I don't know why they don't work any more.

To extract

```
Mr John Smith , Mr James Smith
```

I used this.

```
/\S(.*)\+/  and /\S(.*?)\+/
```

This didn't work. I can't figure out why.

To extract this

```
+(21)-(21)-12345678, 12345678, 12345678                     +(21)-12345678, 12345678, 12345678        SomeTextHereAlso        +(21)-(22)-12345678
```

I used this.

```
/\+(.*)(?=www.)/
```

This did work.

And for url I used

```
/www(.*?)(?=\s\s)/
```

And this works too.

The only problem is the first example that should extract all the characters until the first + but it  extracts all the characters until the last +.

I checked on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2tr5t and the examples I showed here work. Are there any more similar examples that could help me since I looked into the code and didn't find any error.

If regex is fine then how can I use IndexOf() method for this example to extract what I want?

Comment: @missingno’s [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11086693/990363) works, but it shouldn’t be necessary: while your first example (`\S(.*)\+`) uses a *greedy quantifier*, which will try to grab as many characters as possible while still matching and hence ends with the last “+”, the second one (`\S(.*?)\+`) uses a *lazy quantifier*, which tries to match while using the minimum number of repetitions possible. That one should and does stop at the first “+” (say the [spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), and my console agrees).

Comment: I used [This solution][1] help me solve my problem. So my project will be combination of RegEx and IndexOf() method. 

I don't know why RegEx failed on this matter. Thank you all.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690617/javascript-to-match-substring-and-strip-everything-after-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `[^+]+` or more specifically `^[^+]+`

Comment: The first one returned null and the second one worked just as every other example. Returns all characters until the last "+".
I think it might be something with my code but I don't know what. All other functions I made return results just fine only this one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I used [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690617/javascript-to-match-substring-and-strip-everything-after-it) help me solve my problem. So my project will be combination of RegEx and IndexOf() method.

I don't know why RegEx failed on this matter. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the first example, you could just forbid the inner loop from matching "+" characters, using a negated character class.

```
/\S([^+]*)\+/
```

As for extracting the matches, a common pattern is doing something like

```
var myPattern = /someregex/g;
var match;
while( (match=myPattern.exec(theString)) !== null ){
    console.log('the total match', match[0]);
    console.log('the first grouped parenthesis', match[1]);
    //and so on
}
```

---

For example, running

```
var regex = /a(\d+)/g;
var str = ' a100 b200 a300';
var match;
while( (match=regex.exec(str)) !== null ){
    console.log(match)
}
```

prints

```
["a100", "100"]
["a300", "300"]
```

If you have any more doubts, I highly recomend ythe documentation over on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=regex)

Comment: I tried the example you gave me and still I've got the same result. It' matches the every single character until the last "+" sign even though my RegExr says that yours solution work. I will try to come up with something else or maybe try with IndexOf() method.