# javascript find string and delete all the following character

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove everything after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character)

what if I have

```
var shot = www.site.com/ask
```

and I wanted to remove all character after "/" (including "/").
So that the result will be

```
www.site.com
```

NOTE: shot is dynamically changing value
and this will all done on javascript.

Comment: Please post what you have tried till now. Also have you searched answer for your question?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Is shot your current url? If so, you could just use `window.location.host`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove everything after a certain character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631384/remove-everything-after-a-certain-character) and [Javascript to match substring and strip everything after it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690617/javascript-to-match-substring-and-strip-everything-after-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want everything before the `/` you could find the index of the character and return the substring before it:

```
var shot = "www.site.com/ask";
var index = shot.indexOf("/");
var result;
if (index < 0) {
    result = shot;
} else {
    result = shot.substr(0, index);
}
// result = "www.site.com"
```

If you would want to get the domain from a string including the protocol e.g. `http://www.site.com/ask` and get `www.site.com` then you would need to include additional logic as the code above would return `http:`.

Comment: Lets call it "unexpected result", if there is no "/"?

Comment: thank you so much @Smirkin Gherkin it works well :)

Comment: @Bergi, good spot. Included the additional logic to ensure that there is a slash.

Comment: 8 lines of code, with syntax errors, code repetition and a wrong result? realy? I don't get it.

Comment: Should be `if (index >= 0)` (not `<`). Why are you doing the `.indexOf()` twice? (Just use `index` the second time.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, cheers. Must concentrate more.

Answer (score 2):

```
'www.site.com/ask'.split('/', 1)[0]; // => www.site.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var shot = 'www.site.com/ask';
var site = shot.replace(/\/.*$/,'');
```

`site` will now contain www.site.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^(.*?)\//.exec(shot)[1]
```

or:

```
shot.match(/^[^\/]*/)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let the browser do parsing for you:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://" + "www.site.com/ask";
alert(a.hostname);
//"www.site.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest non-regexp way is

```
shot = shot.substr(0, shot.indexOf('/'));
```

But this doesn't account for there being an `http://` or similar. For that, you do need a regexp.

```
shot = shot.replace(/([^\/])\/([^\/].*)?$/, '$1');
```

Comment: The regex doesn't work either. At least, I assume the intention was for `"http://www.site.com/ask"` to end up as `"http://www.site.com"` but that replacement returns `"http:"`.

Comment: Both had typos... the first one I missed the first argument, and the second is fixed too now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regular expression that will remove everything after the first slash

```
var shot = 'www.site.com/ask';
shot.replace(/\/.+/, '');
```